# odoo installation with python and windows 10

Tags: pycharm, odoo

I have installed odoo 12 community edition and pycharm 2019.1 , can anybody help me how can i configure and make my custom module . I seen so many suggestion on internet but nothing work for me.

Comment: check the internet corretly.

Answer (score -1):

There is no other way than reading the docs, hopefully, the following links have enough to get you started:

- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html
- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/guidelines.html
- https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/index.html
- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html